# Textbox size reduces/shrinks on focus

Tags: html, css

On `focus` the size of `textbox` seems reduced/shrinked. But, if the `border-width` is set to `2px` then such reduction can't be observed. I want to set the `border-width` to `1px` but without such reduction like effect. How can it be done?

```css
#name:focus{
 outline:none;
 border:1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
 box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
}

#name2:focus{
 outline:none;
 border:2px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
 box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
}
```

```html
<!doctype  html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  Border-width changes to 1px on focus<br>
  <input type="text" id='name'><p>
  Border-width changes to 2px on focus<br>
  <input type="text" id='name2'><p>
  Default textbox no effects added<br>
  <input type="text" id='check'>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such problem can be solved by introducing `padding` on the `boxes` where ever effect on `focus` has to be added.
I added `padding:2px` on the default setting. `Padding:2px` can be added on `focus` also but your problem can be solved by adding on default setting only. Have a look at the `snippet`.

```css
#name:focus{
 outline:none;
 border:1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
 box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
    padding: 2px;
}

#name2:focus{
 outline:none;
 border:2px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
 box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
}
```

```html
<!doctype  html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  Border-width changes to 1px on focus<br>
  <input type="text" id='name'><p>
  Border-width changes to 2px on focus<br>
  <input type="text" id='name2'><p>
  Default textbox no effects added<br>
  <input type="text" id='check'>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple approaches here. For example you could set the default border-width to 1px(`#name2`) or increase the padding on focus(`#name`).

```css
#name2 {
    border:1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
}
#name2:focus,
#name:focus{
    outline:none;
    border:1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
    box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
}
#name:focus{
    padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype  html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  Padding changes to 2px on focus<br>
  Padding <input type="text" id='name'><br>
  Border default is set to 1px<br>

  Border <input type="text" id='name2'><br>
  Check <input type="text" id='check'>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: inclusion of padding solved the problem. Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
#name:focus{
 outline:none;
 border-color:rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
        border-style: ridge;
 box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
}

#name2:focus{
 outline:none;
 border-color:rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
        border-style: ridge;
 box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
}
```

```html
<!doctype  html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  Border-width changes to 1px on focus<br>
  <input type="text" id='name'><p>
  Border-width changes to 2px on focus<br>
  <input type="text" id='name2'><p>
  Default textbox no effects added<br>
  <input type="text" id='check'>
</body>
</html>
```